# How to debug an application running in Docker with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, docker, remote-debugging

I have a Jetty application running in docker. I would like to debug this application using my local IntelliJ. I am on v 14.1, so I have installed the Docker Integration plugin.

Under Clouds, I am using the default values that showed up when I click on the '+'. IntelliJ docs say this should be OK. Here the

```
API URL: http://127.0.0.1:2376
Certificates folder: <empty>
```

I'm not sure what these are used for, so I dont know if these values are right.

Under Run/Debug configurations, I am using Docker Deployment, and the following values:

```
Deployment: Docker Image
Image ID: The docker image ID 
Container name: The name of the container
```

When I try to run this, I get 
    javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to http://127.0.0.1:2376 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused

Obviously the API URL value I am using is incorrect. Any suggestions on what that value should be?

My debugging options are:

```
 -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sheesh Never mind. I didnt really need the Docker Integration plugin. Seems like that is more for deployment and management of Docker directly through Intellij than for debugging.

To debug my jetty app running inside my docker container, I simply remote debugged:

Run | Edit configurations | + | Remote

The command line args were already OK since I used the default remote debugging options. I only needed to change the Host settings. Here I used the hostname I had set within the docker container

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Using debugging via Docker integration was not working. Now I just run my Docker integration configuration to start the server, then run my remote debugger to debug. Works great.

Comment: @JoppeGeluykens sure. You are basically just connecting to the code like you would on any remote server. It just so happens that this remote server lives inside a docker container.

Comment: @SomaiahKumbera When I configure the remote debugger, I can’t seem to set breakpoints. Any ideas or additional configuration that’s necessary?

Comment: @JoppeGeluykens thats odd. If you get a message from your IDE that you could connect to the remote server, you should be able to set break points. If you cannot, I suspect you are not running the same code as you have in your IDE, in the docker image. Try clicking for break points in several places. If you get mismatched break points, your code is different.

Comment: I don't see the "remote" option when clicking on +. Any solution?

Comment: @ZottoSL - if you go to Run > Debug > Edit configurations, you should see a Run/Debug Configurations window. On the left side, under Templates, you should see an option for Remote.

Comment: Remote option is gone in latest Intellij builds!

Comment: Remote debugging is deprecated

Comment: @Pwnstar I see "Remote JVM Debug" in my version.

Comment: You can create a run target (you dockerfile) in the settings and select that as a target for your run configurations. It's the first option after giving the run configuration a title

Answer (score 12):

Run the docker image like below:

```sh
docker run -d -p 8080:8080  -p 5005:5005 \
    -e JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n" \
    imagename:tagname
```

For java 11 onwards replace JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=*:5005,server=y,suspend=n"

Intellij configuration Steps:

1. From the menu bar click on `run` → `Edit Configurations` → in the left panel click on `Remote` → click on `+` symbol to add the debug config
2. After adding a new config, debug `mode=Attach` to remote JVM. Fill the host and port number
3. Select the module classpath to debug then apply the settings
4. To connect run the above remote config from the `run` menu.

[image: example config]

Comment: You forgot the `-` before `agentlib:jdwp=...` ;)

Answer (score 7):

In Java 8 the JDK supports a JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable so to enable the debugger for any Java application you can add the following parameters to your `docker run` command:

```
-p 8000:8000 -e "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=\"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n\""
```

Then start a remote debug session connecting to localhost:8000.

Comment: this is really nice for configuring it as an env variable with docker-compose :D

Comment: The outer double quotes are not needed: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using docker composer, apply the following changes to Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
ARG JAR_FILE=report-manager/target/*.jar
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Add **ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS** part

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  report-manager:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: report-manager/Dockerfile/
    image: report-manager
    ports:
      - "5032:5032"
      - "5005:5005"
```

Open **5005** port

Then create IntelliJ Idea usual remote debugging configuration and run it after deploying the docker container.

Comment: you can add the env variable on docker compose as well in case you don´t have access to the dockerfile

Comment: for my java container, I needed to put 0.0.0.0:5005 instead of *:5005 otherwise I got a "ERROR: transport error 202: gethostbyname: unknown host"

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wants to do development on windows machine, and run/debug app at same time on a remote docker, you can check my intellij plugin here: https://bojanv55.wordpress.com/2018/08/03/intellij-idea-remote-debug-of-java-code-inside-docker-container/