# Remote debugging Java 9 in a docker container from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, docker, docker-compose, remote-debugging

I have a Dockerfile with this content:

```
FROM openjdk:9

WORKDIR /project

ADD . /project

EXPOSE 5005
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  some-project:
    build: .
    ports:
      - target: 5005
        published: 5005
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
  command: "java '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005' SomeClass"
```

When I do **docker-composer up** I see a message "*Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005*". But when I try to connect with jdb or Idea I get "*java.io.IOException: handshake failed - connection prematurally closed*".

Everything works fine if I change **openjdk:9** to **openjdk:8**. However, I need Java 9 for my project.

Comment: see also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173607

Comment: Check this for the detailed steps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61660010/1734444

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From Java 9, the JDWP socket connector accept only local connections by default. See:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-notes-3745703.html#JDK-8041435

So, to enable debug connections from outside, specify `*:<port>` as address:

`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, not sure why this isn't the accepted answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have specified a debug port on my process (running inside a docker container) and I am exposing the port on my docker-compose. What am I missing?

Comment: You might need to run `docker-compose up --build` to rebuild your image once you've fixed the CMD

Comment: if I am using docker-compose.yml file and the service I want to debug uses a port mapping 8084:8080, do I need to change the port 5005 to 8084 in the debug configuration window ?
and of course, i need to build the image and run docker-compose up, before I start a debug session, right ?