# IntelliJ Unable to remote debug Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I am using IntelliJ 2018.1 to try and debug a remote instance of Tomcat. I followed the directions to setup tomcat here:
https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Setting+Up+Tomcat+For+Remote+Debugging

And I put these startup parameters in the JAVA_OPTS for the Tomcat process.

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=62666,suspend=n,server=y
```

Tomcat is running on a Unix system and when the Tomcat process starts it successfully shows that port 62666 is being listened to. I setup the IntelliJ debug configuration to point to the correct IP and the 62666 port when I start debug.

When I actually run the debugger I get the error:

```
9:23 AM Error running 'Remote INT3': Unable to open debugger port (10.5.0.57:62666): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"
```

When I look at netstat on the remote machine it shows that my local machine is successfully connected to the port 62666. But IntelliJ is obviously not registering that. What is going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps a firewall? Or some other app thats blocking the network traffic like TripMode for example? Tried with a different port?

Comment: There is no firewall or anything like that. On my local machine I do have something called Sophos and Malware Antibytes for Business. These are two programs that I have no control over. I suppose it could be something they are doing. I found a different way to debug my problem though so I no longer need to do remote debugging.

Comment: Those apps might explain it. Anyway glad you've found another way. Feel free to post your own solution and accept as answer for other users with the same issue :-)

Comment: Well, it's technically not an answer to this specific problem. Since my local machine and the server have the same code I just pointed my local tomcat to the specific integration points that the server tomcat was pointed to. This made it so the same data on the server was flowing through my local code, and then I could debug it locally.

Comment: What JDK do you use? If 9+ then the https://stackoverflow.com/a/47772365/2000323 might be the case. Otherwise it seems like a network issue: make sure the remote host/port is really accessible and the socket is opened and IDE processes are not blocked by firewall/AV.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the IntelliJ Remote Development tool:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/remote-development-a.html

Seems like, if it does (now) what you wanted?