# Handshake failed - connection prematurally closed

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I want to setup mi intellij to run mi local environment in debug mod.
In other versions of intellij, i just had to "add new remote" and only when changing to the port to 8080, my debug environment startup correctly, but in this new version, i get the following errors:
"Connection refused: connect" --> When select a not available port (i guess)
"handshake failed - connection prematurally closed" --> the port is accesible but it can't conect.

I attach a screeshot of my debug remote configuration.

Thanks,

Iñigo

[image]

Comment: What JDK do you use to run the application? Might be the https://stackoverflow.com/a/47772365/2000323

Comment: JDK 5-8, but i tried with JDK 9 too