# How to debug maven surefire tests running in a docker container?

Tags: docker, debugging, intellij-idea, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a maven project that contains integration tests and I use the surefire plugin. I can run the tests with

```
mvn clean package
```

and that works fine. I can also remote debug the integration tests using intellij. To do so I execute

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.surefire.debug
```

and in Intellij I create a Run/Debug Configuration of type "Remote" setting Host to localhost and Port to 5005. As soon as the console prints

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

I start the remote debugging in intellij and everything works fine.

The thing is I want to execute the integration tests inside a docker container and especially also debug them inside the container. I have created a docker image with java, maven and all the other stuff my application needs. In the Entrypoint I start my application and then I start the integration tests with

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.surefire.debug
```

inside the docker container. I run the docker container with the option

```
-p 5005:5005
```

to open that port for remote debugging. When running the container, at some point I can see the console output

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

But when I start the remote debugger in intellij, it won't connect but instead gives me the following error message

```
Error running '...':
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.SocketException "Connection reset"
```

and if I try again to start the debugger i get the error message

```
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"
```

But the port should be open, because executing

```
nc -zv localhost 5005
```

in the host (netcat) results in

```
Connection to localhost 5005 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

But if execute the same netcat command inside the docker container it results in

```
localhost [...] 5005 (?) : Connection refused
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? I don't insist on debugging with intellij, but being able to debug the tests inside the docker container somehow would be amazing.

Comment: You need to launch the java in debug mode on the target host - that means inside docker container host. And make sure this host:port is accessible from the host where IDE is run from where you launch remote debug configuration.

Answer (score 6):

The answer actually can be found here: [Remote debugging Java 9 in a docker container from IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662125/remote-debugging-java-9-in-a-docker-container-from-intellij-idea/47772365#47772365)

In my case this means, that running the tests with

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005"
```

solves the problem