# Debugging Java application on Docker

Tags: java, docker, debugging, intellij-idea

I have an issue that I am investigating in a Java application that is hosted in a Docker service. The application is a REST API that has it's own docker service

I have added extra logging and looked into the service logs as well as exec-ing into the container and looking at logs there, but that only gets me to a certain point.

Is there any way to attach a remote debugger, or something similar so that I can step through the code of the application?

Comment: Look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975271/remote-debugging-a-java-application but note that you shouldn’t do this in production

Comment: Depending on the container you are using you should change the command started by the container. Usually you can add parameters passing the JAVA_OPT environment variable. Can you provide some more info about the container?

Comment: @GianlucaMereu My application is deployed using a docker compose file with three different services defined. One of these services is the one which I would like to debug.

Comment: Check this link for detailed steps Visit <https://stackoverflow.com/a/61660010/1734444>?

Answer (score 4):

Dockerfile e.g.:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.1-jdk
VOLUME /tmp
COPY build/libs/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 5005
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005", "-Dspring.profiles.active=localdocker","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

then connect by remote debugger from Idea or Eclipse

Comment: This works. I was missing * in address=*:5005. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also leave your docker file the same if you do something like:

```
VOLUME /tmp
COPY build/libs/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005", "-Dspring.profiles.active=localdocker","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And then on the terminal pass the neccessary arguments

```
docker run -p 5005:5005 <my-container> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005, -Dspring.profiles.active=localdocker,-jar,/app.jar
```

This is the documentation for the connection options for jdwp.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Transports