# How to debug a Glassfish application running with Docker Compose

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, glassfish

I have a Java EE app running on Glassfish, and I have Glassfish running in a container, using Docker and Docker Compose.

I want to know if it's possible to debug this app running on the Glassfish container, as you would debug a regular Java app, from Intellij IDEA.

I've tried something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157900/how-to-debug-an-application-running-in-docker-with-intellij) but it hasn't worked for me.

My `docker-compose.yml` includes (removing other private info):

```
services:
  glassfish:
    tty: true
    build: glassfish
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    - "4848:4848"
    - "80:80"
    - "9009:9009"
```

`Dockerfile` includes (removing other non related info):

```
EXPOSE 8080 4848 80 9009

COPY 010_entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.d/

ENTRYPOINT /docker-entrypoint.d/010_entrypoint.sh
```

And in `010_entrypoint.sh` file (removing other non related info):

```
/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain --debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running glassfish server on a docker is like running it on a remote server so you have to setup remote debugging.

You have t make sure:

a) Your Glassfish server is running in debug mode
b) You have configured port 9009 on your docker so the debugger can connect to it (you need to have a line like this in your docker-compose.yml: - 9009:9009)

Then you have to configure your debugger to connect to localhost:9009

Finally if you share your Dockerfile an docker-compose.yml it will be easier to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm going to edit my question to include the relevant parts of both my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` file (I have to obscure any private info, ofc) for future reference of the SO community, but now it's working! Thanks :D